# Localization issue in Spring with Rx java on new thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, locale, rx-java

I am trying to adapt RxJava to existing Spring project. My aim is to provide WS REST calls asynchronously (I know of `@Async`, but lets ommit this).

The issue is with translations via supplied locale via REST call. In a request, I have a header like this

```
Accept-Language: cs
```

indicating that I want to provide services in desired language. Now `RxJava` kicks in. I created an `Observable` which fetches rows from database and via `Observable.map` operation makes translations with use of

```
LocaleContextHolder.getLocale().getLanguage();
```

The problem is that as in Spring `LocaleContextHolder` specification is stated:

```
Simple holder class that associates a LocaleContext instance with the **current** **thread**.
```

But my subscription of an `Observable` works in new thread pool since it is a costly operation. So my simplified subscription looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/valid", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public DeferredResult<List<CustomerServicesPrintableInfo>> getValidServicesForCustomer() {
    DeferredResult<List<CustomerServicesPrintableInfo>> result = new DeferredResult<>(10000L);
    List<CustomerServicesPrintableInfo> customerServices = new ArrayList<>();
    customerServiceService.getPrintableByCustomerLogin(username)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(customerServices::add,
                    LOGGER::error,
                    () -> {
                        result.setResult(customerServices);
                    });

    return result;
```

but the problem is that once the execution runs in new thread, locale in new thread is default `eng` and not my desired `cs`. If I ommit `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`, everything works fine, but on current thread, which is not desireable.

So the question is - **How can I clearly propagate (or tell Spring/RxJava) that newly created threads shall use incoming locale?**

Comment: Those threads will be reused for multiple requests. Get the locale within the request thread, store it in a local (effectively final) variable and use it explicitly in whatever code needs it.

Comment: So basicaly I have to rewrite all methods to accept also `Locale` parameter, which I'll pass in. And also current logic that locale is gathered from LocaleContextHolder has to be ommited (need to accept incoming). Is that true? In that case, that is a whole bunch of refactoring to do this for all methods.

Comment: The problem with `LocaleContextHolder` is that it stores the context in a `ThreadLocal` and the `.io()` scheduler is a pool that reuses threads, so these are not child threads that can simply inherit threadlocals. You can however put code infront of the code that accesses `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()` and simply do `.setLocale(..)` using the explicit variable from above.

Comment: Understood. But the case is that going this way, some bussiness logic methods (like mentioned `getPrintableByCustomerLogin(username)` have to bear `Locale` parameter, since I cannot set locale in current class. I tried to set `Locale` in `.subscribe()`, but since that is asnyc, result is that not all texts are translated. So I managed to propagate `Locale` to   `Observable`, where I can query translations according to Locale. But I am just interested whether there is a simple way how to indicate underlying observer to use some custom `Locale` and where should that be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is to associate the current thread with the LocaleContext; the easiest way is to create your own schedulers that are aware that they need to pass this to the new threads, and set/reset it when they get to execute.

Comment: Thanks, this solutions seems to fit my problem best.